# Why Equals[A <: B >: B, B] doesn't compile

Tags: scala, type-systems

I use `case class Equals[A >: B <: B, B]` to check type equivalency, e.g.,

```
scala> Equals[Int, Int] 
res0: Equals[Int,Int] = Equals()

scala> Equals[Int, String]
<console>:10: error: type arguments [Int,String] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [A >: B <: B,B]
              Equals[Int, String]
```

But when I re-declare the Equals case class as:

```
scala> case class Equals[A <: B >: B, B]
<console>:1: error: ']' expected but '>:' found.
     case class Equals[A <: B >: B, B]
```

I'd like to know why `[A >: B <:B, B]` works , but `[A <: B >: B, B]` doesn't.

Comment: It looks like in the first case the compiler is just ignoring the  `B <: B` part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Scala Reference Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) item **4.4 Type Parameters**:

> TypeParam ::= (id | ‘_’) [TypeParamClause] [‘>:’ Type] [‘<:’ Type]
>   [‘:’ Type]

Bound sequence is `A >: Lover <: Upper` but not  `A <: Upper >: Lover`